# Manually selecting a multiple drop down option if value is matched in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I need to manually select a dropdown option if a value is matched. Here is the code:

```
if($("#hiddenMyField").val() != "") {
            $("#dropdown").each(function(i){
                 $('option', this).each(function() {
                     if($(this).html() == $("#hiddenMyField").val()) {
                         // code to select the option
                     } else {
                         alert('not matched');
                     }

                 });

            });
        }
```

How can I select the current option located in the drop down if that if condition is met?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options have a `selected` property:

```
this.selected = true;
```

Comment: I tried all of these mentioned methods but to no avail. I am using a multiple drop down list with ui.dropdownchecklist.js (This means that the multiple drop down list is opened as a list of checkboxes. This is required as it is more user friendly. This is a Jquery plugin). Anyone has an idea how I can go around this?

Comment: I tried it on a regular multiple select and it obviously worked as I have used this method some other times. However when I enable the ui.dropdownchecklist.js it won't work anymore. It may be because the items are translated to checkboxes, but I tried this.checked = true as well to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr('selected', true);
```

should do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

All right I managed to find a workaround for this.

Since the options were being translated to divs with checkboxes with the ui.dropdownchecklist.js I first loaded the multiple dropdown with its normal view, then selected the necessary items with the this.selected = true and then I loaded the ui.dropdownchecklist.js function so the items will be translated back to divs with checkboxes. The user doesn't even see the actual multiple checkboxes so this worked out well for me. When they are translated to checkboxes, the selected items are kept and are also ticked when they are transferred.